# Question on how to set new document

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

1. In Photoshop when I set my document there are many unit preferences to choose i.e pixels, inches, cm, mm, points, picas and columns. When can I use them? Do they have the same function?
2. What is a bit? What is the difference between 1, 8, 16 and 32?
3. What is the default Photoshop size?

Answer (score 1):

Use pixels and 8-bit until you have finished reading the Photoshop learning resources and user manual:

[Learn Adobe Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop.html)

Comment: I would go as far as say if you need to ask, then you dont need more than 8 bits